# Ubuntu 18.04 - how to configure zoom

Tags: compiz, colors, accessibility, zooming

Im currently using Ubuntu 16.04 with compizconfig-settings-manager for zoom and invert colors.
I now installed Ubuntu 18.04 on another drive, i wanted to try it out and seems like the zoom works quiet good, but where do i configure it?

I stressed out because the zoomed window kept moving due to mouse tracking i belive or focus.. i always disabled that in compizconfig-settings-manager.

Next is there a keyboard shortcut for inverting colors? theres many bugs with the built in invert function so some windows like the shutdown and menu in right upper corner is in dark color even when high contrast is enabled.

Please understand im not an expert and not dumb, its just impossible when you can't see what's going on on the screen... :)

Comment: May be little helpful https://askubuntu.com/a/1183702/739431

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu and it was due to missing config file.
I fixed it by opening a terminal and typing:

touch ~/.config/zoomus.conf

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. The mentioned dosent seem to do anything in my case.

Answer (score 1):

VIP as well.
You can set shortcuts in settings.

1. **settings-> keyboard shortcuts**
   Start typing shortcuts in settings and keyboard shortcuts appears.
2. scroll to part Universal access
3. click on high contrast on or of and choose your prefered shortcut.

My most popular and used shortcut is turn zoom on or of. 
I`ve also made a shortcut to a script which reads me selected text. which I can share if you want.