# Is there a good screen magnifier for ubuntu that has keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: accessibility

The default one works well, but it doesn't have keyboard shortcuts. Or if it does I can't find documentation of them and thus don't know of them. I just want to be able to magnify the full screen and control the level of zoom with the keyboard and not the mouse. I've tried something called kmag and it works and has shortcuts, but I couldn't figure how to make it full screen. I've only been using this OS for two days and because of lack of magnification I can't read half of what I see, so forgive me my ignorance.

Comment: Hi.. I have written small script.. May be its Similar to your requirement.. Have a look.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1183674/739431

Comment: @YuganTej & Celia have you looked at what Kubuntu has by default? It has a zoom for the entire screen with `Super`+`+` to zoom in and `Super`+`-` to zoom out (until normal) with customizable increments. One can navigate up or down in the document or web page using `Up` and `Down` and set keybinds of your choice to scroll up, down, left, and right on a particular page. No need for the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install xzoom
```

works in 20.04.1
the trick is to drag the mouse from it's zoom screen

to run type magnifier in the app search bar (windows/power key)

Comment: not working me on Wayland, Nvideo Prop. drivers and 22.04.1